# Xdebug not stopping on breakpoint on MacOS High Sierra although is correctly installed

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, macos-high-sierra, phpstorm-2017.2

My development environment is:
- MacOs High Sierra
- PhpStorm
- PHP 5.6
- Apache 2.4
- Xdebug 2.5.5

php config file for xdebug:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php56-xdebug/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=jit
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.force_display_errors=1
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.show_error_trace=1
xdebug.remote_log="/Users/user/www/xdebug_remote.log"
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/Users/user/www/xdebug_profiler"
```

In PHPStorm debug validate tool it seems everything is up and running:

[image]

The xdebug debug log is

```
log opened at 2018-03-21 12:56:51
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" 
xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" 
fileuri="file:///Users/users/www/slt/index.php" language="PHP" 
xdebug:language_version="5.6.33" protocol_version="1.0" appid="2764" 
idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version="2.5.5"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author> 
<![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url> 
<copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2017 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright> 
</init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" 
xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"> 
</response>

Log closed at 2018-03-21 12:56:51
```

To run in debug mode I follow [those steps](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm).

I can't figured out why the breakpoints aren't hit. Anyone can give me some hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not PhpStorm that is listening for port 9000, most probably it's php-fpm.
Change the debugging port to 9001 in PhpStorm and the .ini file.

Comment: Upgrading to High Sierra seems to stop xdebug working on port 9000. This worked for me too.